# I get a double free or corruption error Karatsuba Multiplication (base <=10)

Tags: ubuntu, c++98, double-free

I get a double free or corruption error sometimes when schoolSubtraction is called in the event the first number is less than the second (something context implies is impossible (p1-(p0+p2)). schoolAddition is validated and works for all test cases to add digits in a vector. The assumption in schoolSubtraction that both numbers are equel length is always true due to calls of the zero handler for vectors.

I have tried tracing out, and cannot find where the error occurred

```
std::vector<int> handleVecZero(std::vector<int> V1, int L) {
    std::reverse(V1.begin(), V1.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        V1.push_back(0);
    }
    std::reverse(V1.begin(), V1.end());
    return V1;
}

std::vector<int> schoolSubtraction(std::vector<int> V1, std::vector<int> V2, int B) {
    //V1-V2 and assumed same length vecs
    std::cout << V1.size() << " - " << V2.size() << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < V1.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << V1[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < V2.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << V2[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> ans;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < V1.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << V1[i] << " take " << V2[i] << std::endl;
        if ((V1[i]-V2[i])<0) {
            ans.push_back((V1[i]+B-V2[i]));
            for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
                // std::cout << "yet" <<std::endl;
                if ((ans[j-1]>0)) {
                    // std::cout << "taken from " << i-j << " which was " << ans[i-j] << std::endl;
                    ans[j-1]-=1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    ans[j-1]=B-1;
                }
            }
        } else {
            ans.push_back(V1[i]-V2[i]);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

std::vector<int> karatsubaMultiplication(std::vector<int> V1, std::vector<int> V2, size_t ZeroTrack, int B) {
    std::vector<int> res;
    V1 = handleVecZero(V1, std::max(V1.size(),V2.size())-V1.size());
    V2 = handleVecZero(V2, std::max(V1.size(),V2.size())-V2.size());
    std::vector<int> p0, p1, p2, p, V1U, V1L, V2U, V2L;
    if (V1.size() < 3 && V2.size() < 3) {
            int round = 0;
            for (int i = V2.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                std::vector<int> ans;
                for (int j = V1.size()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    (ZeroTrack >= ans.size()) {
                        ans.push_back((V1[j]*V2[i]+round)%B);
                    } else {
                        ans[ZeroTrack] += ((V1[j]*V2[i]+round)%B);
                        std::cerr << " - " << (V1[j]*V2[i]+round)/B << " - ";
                        if (ans[ZeroTrack]>=B) {
                            ans[ZeroTrack]-=B;
                            ans[ZeroTrack+1]+=1;
                        }
                    }
                    round = (V1[j]*V2[i]+round)/B;
                    ZeroTrack+=1;
                }
                ans.push_back(round);
                std::reverse(ans.begin(), ans.end());
                for (int p = 0; p < 1-i; p++) {
                    ans.push_back(0);
                }
                res = handleVecZero(res, std::max(res.size(),ans.size())-res.size());
                res = schoolAddition(res,ans,B);
                round = 0;
                if (ZeroTrack > 1) {
                    ZeroTrack -=1;
                } else {
                    ZeroTrack = 1;
                }
            }
            return res;
    } else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < V1.size(); i++) {
            if (i < V1.size()/2) {
                V1U.push_back(V1[i]);
            } else {
                V1L.push_back(V1[i]);
            }
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < V2.size(); i++) {
            if (i < V2.size()/2) {
                V2U.push_back(V2[i]);
            } else {
                V2L.push_back(V2[i]);
            }
        }
        V1L = handleVecZero(V1L, std::max(V1L.size(),V1U.size())-V1L.size());
        V1U = handleVecZero(V1U, std::max(V1L.size(),V1U.size())-V1U.size());
        V2L = handleVecZero(V2L, std::max(V2L.size(),V2U.size())-V2L.size());
        V2U = handleVecZero(V2U, std::max(V2L.size(),V2U.size())-V2U.size());
        std::vector<int> del1 = schoolAddition(V1L, V1U, B);
        std::vector<int> del2 = schoolAddition(V2L, V2U, B);
        p0 = karatsubaMultiplication(V1L, V2L, ZeroTrack, B);
        p2 = karatsubaMultiplication(V1U, V2U, ZeroTrack, B);
        V1L = handleVecZero(V1L, std::max(V1L.size(),V1U.size())-V1L.size());
        V1U = handleVecZero(V1U, std::max(V1L.size(),V1U.size())-V1U.size());
        V2L = handleVecZero(V2L, std::max(V2L.size(),V2U.size())-V2L.size());
        V2U = handleVecZero(V2U, std::max(V2L.size(),V2U.size())-V2U.size());
        p1 = karatsubaMultiplication(schoolAddition(V1L, V1U, B),schoolAddition(V2L, V2U, B), 0, B);
        // Necessary Transforms
        std::vector<int> b;
        size_t maxZeroHandle=0;
        maxZeroHandle = std::max(p1.size(),p2.size());
        maxZeroHandle = std::max(maxZeroHandle, p0.size());
        p0 = handleVecZero(p0,maxZeroHandle-p0.size());
        p1 = handleVecZero(p1,maxZeroHandle-p1.size());
        p2 = handleVecZero(p2,maxZeroHandle-p2.size());
        std::vector<int> z = schoolAddition(p2,p0,B);
        p1=handleVecZero(p1,z.size()-p1.size());
        b = schoolSubtraction(p1,z,B);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 2*V2L.size(); i++) {
            p2.push_back(0);
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < (V2L.size()); i++) {
            b.push_back(0);
        }
        b = handleVecZero(b,p2.size()-b.size());
        p0 = handleVecZero(p0,p2.size()-p0.size());
        p = schoolAddition(p2,b,B);
        p = schoolAddition(p,p0,B);
        for (size_t q = 0; q < p.size(); q++) {
            if (p[0]==0) {
                p.erase(p.begin());
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

input (in form of number 1, number 2, base): 492638023618775948882302343403408655761920113817048519624315622726245389531264254792 124981979384285271237499877628063356640550971704683349 10

output:61570875311836896177160171483803585754449032097881406485428574047240260231941510408967012466051516880250861675778266507307838302815858408

Which is Correct
but input: 73 773 2 *** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000007bbe20 *** etc.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was this line:

```
for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
```

(the embedded for loop in the schoolSubtraction method.)
the replacement needed was this:

```
for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
```

I am still interested in knowing how this error caused the numbers to be negative. Surely, it would stop out of bounds access in the case that they were, but how did this change stop the numbers passed to the method from having V1 lower than V2?